# Pass text to program expecting a file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

Related to a question I asked on Stack Overflow: [Passing multiple lines of code to wsadmin.sh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374202/passing-multiple-lines-of-code-to-wsadmin-sh).

I have, as a string, a few lines of input that I need to feed into a command. The command, however, only accepts a file full of input.

Is there some way I could store the lines in a temporary file or pipe which never actually gets written to disk and then feed that directly into the program?

How do I go about acquiring the pipe, feeding the input into it, passing that pipe to the command, and then getting rid of the pipe?

Comment: Can you add an example of the command you're using, and how it's supposed to be invoked?

Comment: Does that mean the program does not accept stdin?

Comment: I agree with both commenters above. It's impossible to suggest anything that may work without knowing the program's specs.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Another solution is to use [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) in Bash. If your system has named pipes, you can use this feature.

It is used like this:

```
program_expecting_a_file <(list)
```

where `list` is a sequence of shell commands (actually pipelines; the full details are [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)). `list` will be executed, and its output will be connected to the pipe. The name of the pipe is then passed to your program.

**NOTE:** spaces are not allowed between `<` and `(`.

(The other substitution `>(list)` also works as you'd expect.)

**In your specific case,** you could use

```
program_expecting_a_file <(echo "$your_strings")
```

although you may find @meuh's solution to be more elegant.

**Update:** A great many usage examples are to be found over at the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Comment: The other two did not work in even the most trivial of cases. Yours passes the tests I've thrown at it so far. I have upvoted yours for now. I will come back and mark this as accepted if it does everything I need.

Comment: Yours works perfectly. If you'd like, you can add it to the related question on StackOverflow and I can accept it over there, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31374202/passing-multiple-lines-of-code-to-wsadmin-sh

Comment: Hi @ArtOfWarfare, glad to be of help. There is a comment over there already with the same proposed solution, so it wouldn't be right for me to post an answer there.

Comment: You posted your solution before he did. Anyways, I've asked him to change his comment to an answer so I can accept it. If neither of you post answers within ~24 hours on that question, I'll just post the answer myself so I can accept it (I don't like leaving my questions as appearing unanswered once I've found what the answer is. It's just bad manners for future readers / potential answerers of the question.)

Comment: Hi @ArtOfWarfare, I'm absolutely fine with what you propose!

Answer (score 20):

You can use a bash **here-doc**. For example,

```
$ cat -n <<<'a
> b'
 1  a
 2  b
```

If you have something in a bash variable you can also interpolate it: eg `<<<"path is $PATH"`.

---

If your command insists on a filename you can give it `/dev/stdin`. Eg:

```
$ sed -f /dev/stdin <<<'s/a/b/'
```

produces the output: `s/b/b/`.

Comment: It's not clear from the question whether the command accepts input on `stdin`, and if not, this isn't going to work. I hope the OP clarifies.

Comment: :( - This seemed super promising, but when I tried it, I got the error message `"-f" option must be followed by a file name.`

Comment: A here-doc is for stdin. If your command absolutely needs `-f` and a filename, then provide the filename `/dev/stdin`. See my edit.

Comment: I think after the edits it's absolutely a viable option!

Comment: +1 for the `/dev/stdin` suggestion.  The program I'm trying to call only accepts a filename, so I've combined `/dev/stdin` with a heredoc.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what is in the script, you *may* be able to use the special filename - (minus) which stands for *stdin*

```
$ mycmd -
Line 1
Line 2
^D
```

Another method which may work for you is to open the file `/dev/fd/0` which again stands for *stdin*.

A third option may be to create a *FIFO* (First In First Out).  That is like a file, but it has two ends to it - you write to one end and read from the other.

```
-- Process 1 --                  -- Process 2 --
$ mkfifo foo
$ cat foo
<waits>                          $ echo hello > foo
hello                            $
$ rm foo
```

Comment: It may be worth noting that the program has to be written to interpret `-` this way - it's not a feature of the shell or the operating system. Though of course most standard Linux utilities do follow this convention, as far as I know.

Comment: Nope. This does not work for the program. There is an interactive mode, but I want to pass the commands to execute to this program from another program, and I don't want to get into rabbit-hole that is `expect`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I have just added a third option that may work.

Comment: Nice answer! The second & third options are basically like the `<()` solution, but more explicit - which may be very useful!

Answer (score 4):

There's another option similar to the `mycmd -` solution, but even for programs which don't handle `-` specifically:

```
$ mycmd /dev/stdin
Line 1
Line 2
^D
```

`/dev/stdin` seems to be OS-related and it works for me on Debian GNU/Linux, but I'm not sure where else it will work, too.

Comment: This seems like it might work, but what is `^D`?

Comment: `^D` is a common notation for pressing Ctrl-D. ^D has the semantics of "end of input stream" here. It's probably more often seen in `^C` or `^Z` which stand for pressing Ctrl-C respectively for pressing Ctrl-Z.

Comment: That does seem to work, but how would I programmatically put stuff into `/dev/stdin` and then close it?

Comment: Just pipe something into that command and it should work, i.e. `cat content | mycmd /dev/stdin`. Just imagine different commands than `cat` here.